# How do I configure the "input format" for the File Tree module?

Tags: input-formats

My question is in the input format step.  How do I "add File Tree to your input format?"

Here are the instructions from the File Tree module:
"Enable the module, and add File Tree to your input format. Then, enter [filetree dir="some-directory"] into the body field of a node, and it will render a list of all the files in that folder. (Note, the folder must reside in your site's "files" folder.)"

When I go to configure the module, I'm taken to
Home » Administration » Configuration » Content authoring » Text Formats

Filtered HTML - anonymous user, authenticated user, administrator
Full HTML - administrator
Plain text - All roles may use this format.

It says "Improper text format configuration is a security risk," so I want to make sure I have this right.  What is it that I need to add where to make File Tree work, safely and securely?

---

I found how to set the input format to use the input filter implemented by the File Tree module:

- Go to text format configuration, accessible again by Home » Administration » Configuration » Content authoring » Text Formats (or by clicking on "Configure" for the File Tree module)
- Click on Full HTML.
- Halfway down, there should be several check boxes, among them one for "File Tree."  Just check that box and you're set.

Now, from here, I still haven't been able to get the module to run. Despite this change, I still see `[filetree dir="dirname"]` printed plainly where I try to insert a file tree.

(This video helped me: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASKqit7kDak.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get File Tree to work, after you set up the input filter, the directory you are referring in `[filetree dir="dirname"]` must be a directory contained in your site's "files" directory. If you want to display all the files in the "files" directory use `[filetree dir="/"]`, or if you want to display a particular directory, put the files in a directory (say, dir1) under files and specify `[filetree dir="/dir1"]`.